# ueventd not reading ueventd.<device_name>.rc

Tags: android-source, android-build

I'm working on a sony Xperia Z1 codename honami, rhine board which works on top of MSM8974 SoC.
Yields after cat /proc/cpuinfo (as expected):

```
Hardware    : Qualcomm MSM 8974 (Flattened Device Tree)
```

in my rootdir I have a ueventd.rhine.rc file which sets a handful of permissions which aren't being set. I tried replacing it with an uevent.qcom.rc instead with no avail.

Any insights?

Answer (score 1):

I figured by my own what was happening. Some sources say that the 
**< device_name >** part as in `ueventd.<device_name>.rc` is supposedly to be taken from the following:

`Hardware    : Qualcomm MSM 8974 (Flattened Device Tree)`

as part of the result fetched from `/proc/cpuinfo`. It's somehow true, but only in a few cases. If init can take this part from the kernel command line it will.

From ueventd.c:

```
/* Respect hardware passed in through the kernel cmd line. Here we will look
     * for androidboot.hardware param in kernel cmdline, and save its value in
     * hardware[]. */
    import_kernel_cmdline(0, import_kernel_nv);

    get_hardware_name(hardware, &revision);

    ueventd_parse_config_file("/ueventd.rc");

    snprintf(tmp, sizeof(tmp), "/ueventd.%s.rc", hardware);
    ueventd_parse_config_file(tmp);
```

Apart from that, my honami hardware is passed to this cmdline, and then is taken, therefore the right name for that file in my system should be ueventd.honami.rc.